# Dropbox not Installing on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: installation, nautilus, dropbox

I'm running a PC with Ubuntu 12.10. I require "Dropbox" to be installed on this machine, and chose to look for it in the "Software Center" and start the installation from there.

The following happens:

1. The Installation starts fine
2. The installation then requires that "Nautilus" be restarted (Dropbox requires Nautilus to be restarted to function properly)
3. I click on the "Restart Nautilus" button
4. Then nothing happens....

The Dropbox Icon shows on the left "Launch Bar", but when you click on it it does nothing as well - except for requesting Authentication.

Answer (score 2):

Try downloading the .deb file and installing it from that. Here is the link to it:

[Download Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/install)

If that doesn't work, you could always try the terminal commands at the bottom of the page - I am used to them, so I just ran them first and faced no problems.

(BTW - when it says you have to restart nautilus, its better to just restart the system)